# Question about holomorphic proper maps

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $U, V$ be connected open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f: U \to V$ which is holomorphic and proper. I am trying to show that $f$ is onto.

Here is my attempt at a proof. Let $A = \{v \in V: \textrm{there exists $u \in U$ with } f(u) = v\}$. I want to show that $A$ is (relatively) open and (relatively) closed in $V$. Then by connectedness of $V$, $A = V$.

I have a question about showing closed. Let $v_{n} \in A$ with $v_{n} \rightarrow v$. Then there exist $u_{n} \in U$ such that $f(u_{n}) = v_{n}$. If $v \in V$, then $\{v_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cup\{v\}$ is compact in $V$ and hence $E = f^{-1}(\{v_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cup\{v\})$ is compact in $U$ and hence as $\{u_{n}\} \subset E$, we may select a subsequence $u_{n_{k}}$ such that $u_{n_{k}} \rightarrow \alpha \in U$ which implies that $f(\alpha) = v$. But what happens when $v \not\in V$?

Comment: You look at the closure of $A$ in $V$, so you are only interested in points $v \in V\cap \overline{A}$.

Comment: @user169575  There is a problem here $\{v_n\}\subset E$? Isn't there exists a sequence $\{u_n\}$ of elements in $U$ such that $f(u_n)=v_n$ and an extraction of it.

Comment: @Hamou: Right, I have fixed the issue.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks! I guess I was just getting confused.